# How to press space key to toggle doubling the size of the rectangle?

Tags: java, processing

```
        float x = 400, y=100;
      int a=20,b=10;
      void setup() { size(800, 200); }
      void draw() {
      rect(x-10, y-5, a, b);
      }
      void keyPressed() {
        int k=' ';
      if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      x++;
      } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      x--;
      } else if (keyCode == UP){
        y--;
      } else if (keyCode == DOWN){
        y++;
      }else if(key=' '){
       a=a*2;
       b=b*2;
        }
      }
```

---

---

Can you teach for me how to press space key you toggle by doubling the size of the rectangle, 1 time, 2 times, 1 time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions.
If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck a description of the problem with your code. It should include a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have a typo: `else if(key=' '){` should be `else if (key == ' '){`.

Comment: Please, indent your code properly. It's very hard to read "as is." [I downvoted because badly formatted code makes it harder to help](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode).

Comment: Crossposted: https://discourse.processing.org/t/how-to-press-space-key-to-toggle-doubling-the-size-of-the-rectangle/7746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go, I added +5 to the x and y because one pixel was too small

```
float x = 400, y=100;

int a=20,b=10;

  void setup() 
  { 
  size(800, 200); 
  }
  void draw() 
  {
   background(200); // to erase the screen everyframe 
   rect(x-a/2, y-b/2, a, b);
  }
  void keyPressed() 
  {
  if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
  x+=5;
  } 
  else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
  x-=5;
  } 
  else if (keyCode == UP){
    y-=5;
  } 
  else if (keyCode == DOWN){
    y+=5;
  }
  else if(key==' '){ //you need to put double equal for checking instead of just one
   a*=2; // same as a=a*2;
   b*=2; // same as b=b*2;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much

Comment: no probleme, thanks for upvoting the post if it was helpful so others can see it